# Docker Failed to fetch deb.debian.org Size mismatch

Tags: docker

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows. I am trying to run the command `docker build -t dtr.server.com/test/jenkins-build-agent-ui:abc123 .` but I got an error

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/a/apt/apt-utils_1.0.9.8.5_amd64.deb  Siz
e mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.4_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pinentry/pinentry-gtk2_0.8.3-2_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg-agent_2.0.26-6+deb8u2_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg2_2.0.26-6+deb8u2_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-apt/python3-apt_0.9.3.12_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dbus-python/python3-dbus_1.2.0-2+b3_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pygobject/python3-gi_3.14.0-1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends     apt-transport
-https=1.0.9.8.4     gnupg2=2.0.26-6+deb8u2     software-properties-common=0.92.25debian1     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lis
ts/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My Docker version is 18.09.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to a [proxy issue](https://community.theforeman.org/t/foreman-installer-1-15-6-1-all-deb-size-mismatch/8203/7) (if you are behind a proxy on your host and have not [configured Docker to use said proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/))

As [said here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004128/apt-get-install-hash-sum-mismatch-for-16-04-but-not-for-17-10):

> this tends to happen sometimes when the archives in the middle of a sync or something, and the hash sums are not completely updated yet on the remote.
>   As the error says, a mirror sync is possibly in progress

As [seen here](http://atoz-chevara.github.io/failed-to-fetch-size-mismatch/), try and delete the `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` folder, and try again. But check first if the proxy allows for anything to be downloaded.

Comment: This exactly related to proxy problem. I asked IT to grant me permission to access through the proxy and the issue resolved.